# How can I have django-taggit tags deleted when there are no more objects attached to them?

Tags: python, django, django-taggit

I think the title says it. Many tags are created and deleted but they still exist even when no more objects are using them.

Is there a way to make it check upon save and delete unused tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only technique I can think of would be to attach a custom `pre_delete` signal handler to every taggable model that checks if it was the last model with any particular tag. In the event that it is, delete that tag.

Comment: do you mean if I should edit the package code or I can have it in my model?

Comment: You can have it in your own models file- you wouldn't have to edit the package code.

Answer (score 0):

If you were willing to edit the package code, you could use the post_delete signal handler defined in the answer here:

[Deleting the tags that are not used by any other object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795878/deleting-the-tags-that-are-not-used?answertab=oldest#tab-top)