# Deleting the tags that are not used by any other object

Tags: python, django, django-taggit

I am trying to modify this file https://github.com/alex/django-taggit/blob/master/taggit/models.py so that when a tag is not associated with any other object, it gets deleted.

Here's what I added to the end of the file:

```
# ---

# Delete the tags that are not used by any other object
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete

def after_deleting(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if TaggedItem.objects.filter(tag=instance.tag_id).count() == 0:
        print "Deleting tag", instance
        t = Tag.objects.get(pk=instance.tag_id)
        t.delete()

post_delete.connect(after_deleting, sender=TaggedItem)
```

It's not working as expected. When I run it give this error:

```
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    Tag matching query does not exist.
```

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: on which of these lines does the exception occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should be using `instance.tag_id` in the filter. Try just using `instance.tag`. Then when finding the tag object you can replace -

```
t = Tag.objects.get(pk=instance.tag_id)
```

with -

```
t = instance.tag
```

Adding _id to a field is a shortcut for getting the primary key of an object. So `instance.tag` is the tag object and `instance.tag_id` is the primary key of the tag object.

The whole thing would be more succinct -

```
# Delete the tags that are not used by any other object
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete

def after_deleting(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if not TaggedItem.objects.filter(tag=instance.tag):
        print "Deleting tag", instance
        instance.tag.delete()

post_delete.connect(after_deleting, sender=TaggedItem)
```

Comment: I am getting this error with your code: Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 
'int' object has no attribute 'delete'
Exception Location: /Users/azio/.virtualenvs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/taggit/models.py in after_deleting, line 172
Python Executable: /Users/azio/.virtualenvs/proj/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3

Comment: I'm afraid the whole premise of my answer was wrong :( Anyway I've updated it - I think this version should work fine.

Comment: Django Version: 1.4.2
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value: 
Tag matching query does not exist.
Exception Location: /Users/user/.virtualenvs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in get, line 366
Python Executable: /Users/user/.virtualenvs/proj/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3